# Using Binning before Mann–Whitney for Temperature Data

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, mean, paired-data, binning

I have daily temperature for 2 cities, and I am trying to see if we can conclude that one city is warmer than the other. I could use a Mann–Whitney for a whole year, or I can bin the temperature into maybe weeks or 2–3 days at a time. Maybe I can use a Chi-squared? Are there also technical issues (not related to area knowledge, i.e., how temperature is experienced) to consider when binning?

Comment: If you're comparing the two cities for the same year, then I wonder if you have paired data. If so, you want Wilcoxon signed rank test for 365 days. If you want to compare 'how temperature is experienced' maybe you want a temperature index that takes humidity and wind into account: 'feels-like' temperatures. // Your description is sketchy and telegraphic, but just from what you say, I see no advantage to binning.

Comment: @BruceET: I don't get it, if I have data for each city taken at each day, how is not paired data?

Comment: I'm saying I think it is paired data. But don't use Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon 2-sample test for paired data.

Comment: Beware; these are time series; the temperature differences are not going to be independent. I agree with "don't bin" advice; it's rarely beneficial. Sometimes it doesn't hurt much.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica: I worry too about variance of individual data points being high-enough that ranks may be flipped, e.g., if the difference in one day is 0.8 but variance is 1. How would we address this?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; that doesn't seem to relate to the points being made.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica: Yes, it is somewhat -oblique, maybe unrelated. Maybe an example illustrates best: If temp1 =23, temp2=22 and variance(temp1)=3 , then 20<temp1<26, so that  temp1> temp2 may not be reflective of the " True Rank".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is temperature time series, there is certainly autocorrelation, which must be taken into account. Let the time series be $Y_{jt}, j=1,2;\quad t=1,2 \dotsc, T$. Since the interest is in the paired comparison calculate the difference time series $D_t = Y_{2t}-Y_{1t}$. The mean temperature difference can be estimated by the mean of $D_t$ (other estimators as the median or some trimmed mean ... could replace the mean).

But the autocorrelation makes it non-trivial to find the standard error of this estimate. Some ideas:

1. Estimate the autocorrelation function and use it to find the se.
2. Use [moving block bootstrap?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=time-series++block+bootstrap+answers%3A1)
3. Calculate an autocorrelation-resistant standard error?

Related Qs on site with interesting answers:
[Determining standard error of the mean from a correlated, stationary time series using known autocorrelation without block averaging](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/459130/determining-standard-error-of-the-mean-from-a-correlated-stationary-time-series),
[How to estimate confidence interval of the sample mean of a non-stationary time series?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81843/how-to-estimate-confidence-interval-of-the-sample-mean-of-a-non-stationary-time),
[T-test in the presence of autocorrelation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/363825/t-test-in-the-presence-of-autocorrelation),
[Estimating accurately the mean of an autocorrelated bounded integer time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194389/estimating-accurately-the-mean-of-an-autocorrelated-bounded-integer-time-series),
[Calculating error of mean of time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/274635/calculating-error-of-mean-of-time-series),
[Newey-West t-statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43898/newey-west-t-statistics)